# Run polynote with custom config

Tags: scala, polynote

I have a couple of custom config files to work with polynote. So far I have created a symlink to load the desired configuration, but that seems a bit cumbersome. Is there a way to pass a path to the configuration, for example as a run parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [sourcecode](https://github.com/polynote/polynote/blob/c1e7fc02b8a5df90f41b6ef65e46ebb368bd4a47/polynote-kernel/src/main/scala/polynote/app/package.scala#L48) there is:

```
--config newconfig.yml
```

or

```
-c newconfig.yml
```

Actually, docs should be available once you [list all commands](https://github.com/polynote/polynote/blob/632ece13b1a6d0ce78b8f66f866dcde79feceda2/polynote-server/src/main/scala/polynote/NotebookRunner.scala):

```
polynote.py run ---config custom-config.yml notebook
```